# Swift 3 NSPredicate relationship request returns empty array

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, swift3, nsfetchrequest

I have a big problem right now. I just updated my app to Swift 3 and with the Help of Stackoverflow I got everything running smooth so far, except for the predicates where i try to access a relationship.

This is my old request which worked just fine with Swift 2.3

```
if let myStation = station {
        context.performAndWait {
            let request = ProcessDetail.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<ProcessDetail>
            // DOESNT WORK ANYMORE !!!!! NEW SWIFT
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "process.station_ID = %@", myStation.station_ID! )

            do {
                let processDetails = try context.fetch(request)
                for processDetail in processDetails {
                    ansProcessDetails += 1
                    if processDetail.processdetail_checked == "yes" {
                        ansMasteredProcessDetails += 1
                    } else {
                        ansNotMasteredProcessDetails += 1
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

But now with the Array of processDetails is empty. Any suggestions?

Here is the important line of code again:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "process.station_ID = %@", myStation.station_ID! )
```

Thanks Ben

Comment: what type is station_ID ?

Comment: Try once `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K = %@", "process","station_ID", myStation.station_ID! )`

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk station_ID is of type Sting

Comment: @NiravD Nice try, but didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: Also try like `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K = '%@'", "process","station_ID", myStation.station_ID! )`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, it never does implicit bridging conversions fully according to this thread:https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md

Maybe, station_ID is String type?
So you can try with this:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "process.station_ID = %@", myStation.station_ID as! NSString)
```

Let me know if it fixed your issue
Sincerely

Comment: Thanks for the articel will give it a look.
Tried the casting as a NSString but didn't work.
The problem is that even if i try something like that

'request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "process.station = %@", myStation.station)'

Which always worked for me i get an empty array back.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it will help your issue.

Comment: if I can review your code and fix locally, it will be good.. through debugging, I could find the issue.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the offer. I am unfortunately not allowed to upload code because it is a project for a company. I actually found the solution just now. Am a bit ashamed actually. My data base had an error which messed up all the relationships. Thanks for the help again

Comment: I am glad to hear you solved the issue. That's the reason why I requested to debug your actual code base. If you think I helped you somewhat, hope to get your vote :) This is my first experience here!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, am using this for search in swift 3 and it is working in both swift 2.3 and swift 3. It returns proper array.

/*

```
NSPredicate(format: "process.station_ID CONTAINS[c] %@",myStation.station_ID)
```

*/

Let me know, if it fixed your issue.

Thanks Mandeep Singh

Comment: hmm couldn't get it to work. Very frustrating because everything was working perfectly in swift 2.3. But maybe sth else broke and I am looking for the mistake at the wrong position. Thanks for the help anyway